# Get outputs from cells which matches certain condition and create a dict with value as list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, google-sheets

I was trying to generate a dictionary which is with a value of list which contains certain values from google sheet cell. I was able to get the output separately each time but not able to append those values together into a list.
Here is the print format of the cell values(get_SW_data) I'm working on,
[['SW1', 'Port 1', 'CSW1'], ['SW1', 'Port 2', 'CSW2'], ['SW2', 'Port 1', 'CSW1'], ['SW2', 'Port 1', 'CSW1']]

I'm trying to get SW1 port values into a list and add it into a dictionary.
Here is the code,

```
for x in get_SW_data:
if x[0] == "SW1":
port = x[1]
port_dict = {
        "ports" : port
    }
print(port_dict)
```

This gives me the output,
**{'ports': 'Port 1'}
{'ports': 'Port 2'}**
[image: Google Sheet Image for ref]
But I want something like this,
*{'ports': ["Port 1", "Port 2"]}*

Answer (score 1):

You can create empty list first and append port value to the list in each iteration. Create a dictionary data using the list.

```
ports_list = []
for x in get_sw_data:
    if x[0] == 'SW1':
        ports_list.append(x[1])
port_dict = {'ports': ports_list}
print(port_dict)
```